# How to secure JSON-RPC endpoint with a NFT token?

Tags: go-ethereum

I see how to setup an ethereum node with NGINX as a proxy and basic http access control in order to protect my node to be used and abused by third parties.

> https://medium.com/coinmonks/securing-your-ethereum-nodes-from-hackers-8b7d5bac8986

I'm trying to figure out how to replace the http access control and instead check token ownership from a ERC721 smart contract using the balanceOf method any ideas on how to implement a middleware, can I use express to output the response ?

[How can an app using the web3 rpc api be secured?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21569/how-can-an-app-using-the-web3-rpc-api-be-secured)

Answer (score 0):

You can use client-side certificate to secure your node's incoming connections.

To do so, implement your own variation of `HttpProvider` ([example](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/1.x/packages/web3-providers-http/src/index.js)), just allow to send client side certificate. You can also pin your node's self-signed certificate.

Now define a CA for your backend, create and self-sign a certificate for the node, also create and sign a cert for the client.

In `nginx.conf` define the node cert and require client to be signed by your CA -

```
    server {
        listen          443 ssl http2;
        server_name     your.local.host;

        ssl_certificate      server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  server.key;

        ssl_client_certificate ca.crt;
        ssl_verify_client on;
        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-CERT              $ssl_client_cert;
        proxy_set_header    x-ssl-verify            $ssl_client_verify;

        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        location / {
            proxy_pass          http://localhost:8545;
        }
    }
```

Your node will now be available through `https://your.local.host` and require a client-side cert signed by CA. That's about the safest as can be.

Comment: The variation of the HttpProvider needs to be on the server side how can I implement this ? I'm use to using express with nodejs how to send an error or let the request pass if the person is authorized with json-rpc and my nodejs api ?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to figure out how to replace the http access control and instead check token ownership from a ERC721 smart contract using the balanceOf method any ideas on how to implement a middleware, can I use express to output the response ?

Such check is not possible in Nginx, or any web server middleware, or is prohibitively complex. However you could do this at the application layer with using [Sign in with Ethereum](https://login.xyz/).